# Market vs. limit order data

Tags: limit-order, market-order, market-data

I  can get limit order data (the 'order book') at various levels of detail from my broker  - what I'm interested in is the stuff that's not on  the books (afaict), namely the market orders - is there a way to obtain  that data , or can I infer it from the volume and order book data (e.g.  assume any book orders that disappeared when SP hit their level was  executed, any volume beyond that was limit orders)?